How can a class have a primary constructor and guarantee that its a singleton?
I'l admit that our testing framework would benefit from a significant refactor and this could be solved by better DI. However, I need to work with what I have for now.
As part of the testing framework, I want to create a class that initialises many documents. These documents are submitted to the system, and the results cached and reused. To simplify declaring how each document is initialised, I'd rather use a primary constructor. Without a primary constructor, each document would need to be specified twice, once for the member, once to initialise it in the constructor.
public class SharedDocuments(Config config)
{
    public Document Alpha = new DocumentBuilder(config).AsType("Alpha").Build();
    public Document Beta = new DocumentBuilder(config).AsType("Beta").Build();
    //TODO: Many more documents.

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Document, Task<DocumentResult>> submittedDocuments = new();

    public Task<DocumentResult> UseDocument(Document document) =>
        submittedDocuments.GetOrAdd(document, SubmitDocument);

    private async Task<DocumentResult> SubmitDocument(Document document)
    { ... }
}

To ensure documents are not submitted multiple times, this class should be a singleton that is reused in all cases to protect against human error initialising multiple caches. How can this class cleanly enforce that it is a singleton? Thread safety during initialisation is not a concern.
I've tried a few things. This makes a singleton, but only if Instance is called. How can I make the primary constructor private to prevent creating more instances?
public class SharedDocuments(Config config)
{
    public static SharedDocuments Instance { get; private set; }

    public static void Initialise(Config config)
    {
        if (Instance is not null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already initialised. Use Instance instead.");
        Instance = new(config);
    }
}

The only solution I have so far is to include a nested class that manages the singleton state. It's ugly and would love to use something closer to the above code if possible.
public class SharedDocument(Config config)
{
    [SuppressMessage("CodeQuality", "IDE0052"] // Remove unread private member 
    private readonly Singleton singleton = new();
    private class Singleton
    {
        private static bool isInitialised = false;

        public Singleton()
        {
            if (isInitialised)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Already initialised. Use Instance instead.");
            isInitialised = true;
        }
    }
}


I don't like the idea, but if we are talking theoretical hacking, this will work:
public class SharedDocuments(Config config) {
    private static bool instanceInitialized = false;
    // field initialization is injected into the constructor
    // by the c# compiler so method call below is guaranteed to run
    // when primary constructor is invoked
    private int singletonGuard = CheckInitialized();

    private static int CheckInitialized() {
        if (instanceInitialized) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already initialised");
        }
        instanceInitialized = true;
        return 42;
    }

    public static SharedDocuments Instance { get; private set; }

    public static void Initialise(Config config) {
        Instance = new(config); // will throw, alternatively we can make check static field here too
    }
}


Yeah, that's the same principal as the Singleton private class, but nicer. Thanks!

You would like to make the primary constructor for SharedDocuments private, but you can't because the language syntax does not support different class modifiers for the class and constructor parameter list:

class_declaration
  : attributes? class_modifier* 'partial'? class_designator identifier type_parameter_list?
  parameter_list? class_base? type_parameter_constraints_clause* class_body
  ;


As a workaround, since you want to be able to initialize Alpha et. al. with field initializers rather than in the constructor, you could make SharedDocuments be abstract and implement it with some private nested class like so.  Doing so provides compile-time protection against accidentally constructing multiple instances of ShardDocuments:
public abstract class SharedDocuments(Config config)
{
    static SharedDocuments instance;
    
    public static SharedDocuments GetInstance(Config config)
    {
        if (instance is null)
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref instance, new ConcreteSharedDocuments(config), null);
        // TODO: should you check to see whether instance.Config == config?
        return instance;
    }

    private class ConcreteSharedDocuments(Config config) : SharedDocuments(config);

    // Remainder as before:
    
    public Document Alpha = new DocumentBuilder(config).AsType("Alpha").Build();
    public Document Beta = new DocumentBuilder(config).AsType("Beta").Build();
    //TODO: Many more documents.

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Document, Task<DocumentResult>> submittedDocuments = new();

    public Task<DocumentResult> UseDocument(Document document) =>
        submittedDocuments.GetOrAdd(document, SubmitDocument);

    private async Task<DocumentResult> SubmitDocument(Document document)
    { 
        // Dummy implementation since the actual implementation was not included in the question.
        var result = await Task.FromResult(new DocumentResult(document));
        return result;
    }
}

It would still be possible for your abstract class to be mistakenly subclassed and constructed elsewhere, but this seems much less likely than a mistaken use of a public constructor.
Mockup fiddle here.
As an alternative, you might consider replacing your current design with a more traditional sealed static singleton using a traditional constructor whose Document values are properties backed by a lazily initialized concurrent dictionary, like so:
public sealed class SharedDocuments
{
    private readonly Config config;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Document>> documents = new();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Document, Task<DocumentResult>> submittedDocuments = new();
    static SharedDocuments? instance;
    static Func<DocumentBuilder, DocumentBuilder> defaultConfigure = d => d;

    private SharedDocuments(Config config) => this.config = config;

    public static SharedDocuments GetInstance(Config config)
    {
        if (instance is null)
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref instance, new SharedDocuments(config), null);
        // TODO: should you check to see whether instance.Config == config?
        return instance;
    }
    
    private Lazy<Document> GetDocument([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", 
                                       Func<DocumentBuilder, DocumentBuilder>? configure = default) => 
        documents.GetOrAdd(memberName, _ => new(() => (configure ?? defaultConfigure)(new DocumentBuilder(config).AsType(memberName)).Build()));
    
    public Document Alpha => GetDocument().Value;
    public Document Beta => GetDocument().Value;
    //TODO: Many more documents.

    // Remainder as before:
    public Task<DocumentResult> UseDocument(Document document) =>
        submittedDocuments.GetOrAdd(document, SubmitDocument);

    private async Task<DocumentResult> SubmitDocument(Document document)
    { 
        // Dummy implementation since the actual implementation was not included in the question.
        var result = await Task.FromResult(new DocumentResult(document));
        return result;
    }
}

This architecture guarantees that SharedDocuments will only be constructed one and has the added advantage that each document is constructed only once, when actually used.
Mockup fiddle #2 here.

yeah, good solution if we would live with all the limitations of abstract classes

For this to work, would each Document need to be specified in both SharedDocuments (for the member) and ConcreteSharedDocuments (for the initialiser)? If so, then a single class with an explicit constructor would have similar verbosity and be easier to manage.

@Hand-E-Food - no, ConcreteSharedDocuments would not need to have any mention of the documents or any other code than the single line of code that is shown.  I added a [mcve] and a link to a mockup fiddle.

@tinmanjk - yeah, good solution if we would live with all the limitations of abstract classes -- what limitations of abstract classes apply to a static singleton?  There's no requirement to deserialize or copy it, is there?

@dbc - you are correct. I was mistakenly thinking of something that is not a concern with the class being abstract. The requirement of this being a singleton still applies though and you mentioned the issue of subclassing yourself (which some might argue does not make it a real singleton). Anyway, may the best hack win.

@tinmanjk - If you are really paranoid there's no reason not to add both compile-time and fallback run-time protection against creation of multiple instances.  If this class is intended to be used by third party developers (e.g. customers) then that could make sense.  If it's only for in-house use in some testing framework I would say that compile time protection is sufficient, but you didn't specify a threat model in your question so I can't say for sure.

@dbc I didn't ask the question. I provided the other answer half-jokingly cause I think this use case is not for primary constructors. Feel free to comment on it if you see drawbacks compared to your approach.

@Hand-E-Food - alternative design suggested

Thanks for that banter!  Yeah, it's just inhouse stuff. The current pattern is that test framework services are instantiated where they're needed rather than using DI. I have fears that someone will, without understanding, do the same with this, negating its benefits. A runtime failure is sufficient as that will at least prevent them from merging changes with incorrect usage.
